# Unexpected '{' and 'else'

Tags: r, if-statement, curly-braces

Trying to make a function where a vector for "scores" can be saved, and then this function would determine the qualitative rating of the score. I've rearranged my brackets multiple times, but I still get those errors. Also getting errors with the "else" as well.

```
    credit_fun <- function(scores){
      if (scores>300 & scores<579)(incbounds = TRUE){
    'Very Poor';
    } else if (scores>580 & scores<669)(incbounds = TRUE){
    'Fair';
    } else if (scores>670 & scores<739)(incbounds = TRUE){
    'Good';
    } else if (scores>740 & scores<799)(incbounds = TRUE){
    'Very Good';
    } else if (scores>800 & scores<850)(incbounds = TRUE){
    'Exceptional'}
}
```

Comment: so if ((scores>300 & scores<579)(incbounds = TRUE)) ?

Comment: ah ok, let me try that

Comment: ok the unexpected 'else' went away for all of them, but still getting "unexpected '{' for every line

Comment: not completely sure about that, my peer included that. I think it's to make sure that the values remain within the bounds? Is it unnecessary if I have the constraints in the if statement?

Comment: I ditched the incbounds, it did get rid of the error. It only returned the first value in the vector though. How would I adjust the function to make it compatible with vectors of various lengths?

Comment: Your post doesn't include a small reproducible example.  So, I am not sure about the lengths, expected output etc.  If te length of two vectors are greater than 1 and not the same, it needs different logic because `if/else` takes only a single element and returns single element.  Instead you may need `ifelse`

Comment: I have scores saved as scores <- c(840, 400, 750)

Comment: For the future you should realize that `=` is not the logical test operator in R. For that purpose use `==`. Furthermore, writing `incbounds = TRUE` besides being incorrect use of the `=` operator would become redundant. If you were to substitute `incbounds == TRUE`,  that operation would return TRUE when `inbounds` is `TRUE`; `FALSE` when it is `FALSE`; and `NA` when it is `NA`, so nothing is gained by the test.

Comment: There's also multiple other possilbe issues with this code. If `case_when(between(...))` resolves your issue, then you probably should ahve been using `ifelse` rather than `if`. and putting two parentheses enclosed expressions in a row after an `if` is also going to throw syntactic errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `between` and `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
credit_fun <- function(scores) {
      case_when(between(scores, 300, 579) ~ "Very Poor",
                between(scores, 580, 669) ~ "Fair",
                between(scores, 670, 739) ~ "Good",
                between(scores, 740, 779) ~ "Very Good", 
                TRUE ~ "Exceptional")

  }
```

---

Or another option is `cut`

```
credit_fun <- function(scores) {
           cut(scores, breaks = c(-Inf, 300, 580, 670, 740, Inf),
                 labels = c("Very Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Exceptional"))
  }
```

Or with `findInterval`

```
credit_fun <- function(scores) {
   c("Very Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Exceptional")[findInterval(scores, 
                 c(300, 580, 670, 740))]
  }
```

Comment: I'm very new to R and I only downloaded the base R package. I'm getting a 
 "could not find function `case_when`"

Comment: @user12996093 you can use `cut` or `findInterval`, it is from `base R`.  For the `case_when`, it is from `dplyr`.  Try `install.packages('dplyr')` and then load `library(dplyr)`

Comment: The cut function worked perfectly. Had to adjust the breaks to the top end of the range to limit the max for each range since 750 was showing as Exceptional. Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: I suppose this is useful but don't you think it would be more helpful to also point out the glaring errors in the original code? (Surprised you didn't use `findInterval` :-)

Comment: Oh, wait, there it is, off to the side.

Comment: @42- Yes, in the comments I did pointed out the errors, but later I removed those comments.